# Google Places Web API radarsearch with opennow doesn't give any results

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

When I'm trying to do a `radarsearch` with https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=50.938932362073544,6.959884464740753&radius=3000&type=night_club|bar&key=CENSORED_KEY&opennow=true

I don't get any results but if I discard the `opennow` parameter it returns over 200 places. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), that the parameter `opennow` only returns places that were open for business at the time the query is sent. Also, take note that places that do not specify opening hours in the Google Places database will not be returned if you include this parameter in your query. So make sure you use this parameter correctly, and make sure that your request places are in Google Places database.